# How to avoid copying same folder using batch

Tags: batch

I have a batch which downloads latest folder and copying to a particular destination from particular Source path but Its dowloading the latest file among the available folder in source path even if the already copied/available in destination path.I want to avoid the repetation  of copying same file .

Comment: What OS are you using? It's hard to answer without knowing.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXIST filename (
REM Do one thing
) ELSE (
REM Do another thing
)
```

Here is a link with help on IF statements. http://www.robvanderwoude.com/if.php

This is for windows batch files